# Auctions searching, filtering and sorting

Tags: php, elasticsearch, architecture

I want to use elasticsearch for search and filter auctions list (specified auctions categories have an extra fields witch can be filtred).
But for bids and price managment i want to use postgresql (elastic could have quite big delay).

Witch way is the best to get auctions filtered by elasticsearch and sorted by price (postgresql)?

My solution (idea) is redundantion:

**When someone bid:**

1. update price in postgresql (fast and reliable)
2. update price in elasticsearch (possible delay).

**When I fetch auctions list (endless pagination):**

1. Full elasticsearch query (searching, filtering) with sorting by price.
2. Verify result items price with PostgreSQL..

Drawbak: Some items could be incorrect sorted.

Is the better or easier way?

Comment: So your goal is to do a two-step query? Fetch from ES, then sort by Postgres?

Comment: My goal is to get a set of records satisfying the conditions. Some conditions are almost unchanged and some are very important and rapidly changing (like price). Two-step query is just my idea now :)